# Notion API Unsaved transactions: Unrecognized error

Tags: node.js, reactjs, notion-api, notion

Please help, I'm new to Notion...

I have a server.js file that make a request to notion API to create the row in notion DB. Yesterday it was working correctly, the row with all the data was created and I saw it in the UI version. I tried to handle the case when user leaves the page - to save the data to notion anyway. There were some validation errors, but I fixed them. Then I got the error

```
   data: {
      object: 'error',
      status: 400,
      code: 'validation_error',
      message: 'Unsaved transactions: Unrecognized error.'
    }
```

I removed all the new code with git stash and returned to the previous working version. Rebuilded the project, started the server once again, and reloaded the page.  But I still get the same error.

Answer (score 1):

It appears to happen when updating a database.

No problem retrieving data, just when adding or changing it.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

This issue had occurred before even when duplicating templates. However, this time the issue was with `checkbox` fields when trying to update it.
The issue was due to an update from Notion Dev which was rolled back. More details of the incident [here](https://status.notion.so/incidents/5xq6jc04sf0b).
Issue was resolved after 24 hours of downtime.